# How do I get added/changed files in a pre-commit hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I want to write a hook that checks certain coding conventions in files being committed, and if those are violated, rejects the commit/push. However, in my "rejection message" I want to tell the committer the line numbers, where the violations have been found.

The best I can think of so far is to get the whole file being committed, that will allow me to count the lines. That will also allow me to find the same coding convention violations in earlier code, so that the programmers will have to clean up the whole file they happened to modify.

Is it at all possible? How can I get the whole new file being committed.

Comment: why don't you just check all files in the whole source folder? wouldn't it make sense to check for coding standards on *all* of the code, not just new files or changes?

Comment: @NevikRehnel The thing is that if a piece of code is already in the repository, it makes sense to suppose that it has been checked. It seems, i can just read the whole modified file from the filesystem. I will try that now.

Comment: Turns out, that what you see on your file system is not what you are committing, because the changes need to be staged. That is, we need to read the staged files...

Comment: Then you're probably looking for [`git cat-file`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file)

Comment: @NevikRehnel Yes, that helped. If you post it as a reply, I will be happy to accept it. Thank you.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50278347/1830614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the content of any Git object with [`git cat-file`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file) (you can also use it to find out the type of the object first, just to be sure).

As you have pointed out in the comments to your question, reading a file from the filesystem directly does not always work because it might not be fully staged, or it might have changed since being staged.